# $x^2\over {x^3+2}$ is an unbounded

Tags: calculus, functions

How can I prove that $x^2\over {x^3+2}$ is an unbounded function?
Let $M>0$ I need to prove that there exists an element $x_M$ in the domain of the function such that $f(x_M)\ge M$

If I Put $M={x^2\over {x^3+2}}$  I need to solve it for $x$, but I don´t know if there is an easier way to do it.

I would really appreciate if you can help me with this problem. Any comments, suggestions or hints would be highlt appreciated.

Comment: You could take the derivative. if the derivative is monotone non-decreasing over an interval of length infinity that would do .

Comment: at cube root of -2 you get a k/0 situation. Analyze the function about that point: it goes arbitrarily high and low.

Comment: It is well known when you have a vertical asymptope that the function blows up to +/- infinity on either side.

Comment: Isn't there a max at $2^{3/2}$? If you only consider $\mathbb{R}^+$, then it is bounded.

Comment: It is almost the same as (x^2)/(x^3) which obviously is unbounded as 1/x .

Answer (score 2):

When $x$ tends to $-(2^{1/3})$ from below, the function tends to $+\infty$ and when $x$ tends to $-(2^{1/3})$ from above, the function tends to $-\infty$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can factor the denominator and compute the partial fraction expansion:

$$1/3\,\left({\frac {-\sqrt [3]{2}+2\,x}{{x}^{2}-x\sqrt [3]{2}+
{2}^{2/3}}}\right)+1/3 \,\left(1\over x+\sqrt [3]{2}\right).$$

The first term is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and so it's bounded.  So you can reduce your problem to showing that the second term is unbounded.